# Windows 10 - how do I track what's running during sleep

Tags: windows-10

During the last few months something has changed on my Dell XPS 15 (Windows 10 Pro). Perhaps due to an update, I don't know - I haven't installed anything new on this laptop in a long, long time (it's mainly a software development box). Very often, almost always, when I put it to sleep (manually or by closing the lid) something, some process spikes and starts eating up the battery. It seems like as soon as I close the lid some process ramps up. Every time.

If I jump right into the Task Manager when I open it back up all I ever see is the Anti Malware Executable running hot but only for a few seconds. Is there anything I can run that will monitor it while it's in sleep mode to help me find the culprit? Pretty much sucks having to shut it off all the time - I don't think I shut it off more than twice for the first 3 years I owned it but now I have to shut it down all the time...

Any suggestions for a tool or application I can use to find the miscreant process?

Comment: Why not *hibernate*? It uses *no* battery power.

Comment: Make sure your settings are correct.  A recent change on my Laptop (driver and/or update) change the Lid Close setting to do "Nothing" . So it did not really suspend. I have fixed that and nothing significant runs when suspended.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - huh, didn't think of that, haven't changed power settings in years. Changed _sleep_ to _hibernate_ when the lid closes and I'll try it out today. Thanks!

Comment: @John checked it out - the power settings (which _still_ haven't made it to the new settings app...) were set to sleep - I changed it to hibernate and will give it a shot.